# Get Current SPWeb From Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm working on a WebPart, to be used in SharePoint, that will display a listing of documents within a document library. To do so, I believe I need to reference the SPWeb object for which the web part is hosted on. Unfortunately, I don't see how to access the current SPSite or SPWeb from within a WebPart. How would I access these from within a WebPart?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the static [`SPContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475883.aspx) property to get access to your SharePoint environment. From `SPContext` you can get access to both the current `SPWeb` and `SPSite`.

```
SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPSite mySite = SPContext.Current.Site;
```

Comment: I didn't even notice the SPContext property. Thank you very much!